# Can we use python yield and create a generator object for audio data in .wav format and get them back?

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio, pydub, python-sounddevice

I want stream my data(audio) from my pc to server. During this process I am ending up saving files on server. I want some suggestions on how I could use the data I stream to server without saving the data on the server. I got to know about python generators. I have seen many tutorials online but ended up dealing data with lists and other data. I didn't find anything related to this. I would be really thankful if you can help me in this.

Comment: Can you post the code that saves the audio to the disk?

Comment: I was using this library to handle the socket programming "https://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html". I was making a list of the data I receive and then make it a wav file using the function I am sharing in another comment below

Comment: def _write_to_file(self, data,filename):
        out_filename =  filename;           
        file = wave.open(out_filename, 'w');
        file.setnchannels(1);
        file.setsampwidth(2);
        file.setframerate(8000);
        file.writeframesraw(data);
        file.close();
        return out_filename;